# Java Database with PHP support

Tags: java, php, database, sharing

I'm looking for a java database server that has support for database to be shared and opened from a PHP web application and a java application simultaneuosly.

I found Apache Derby and H2 Database but they don't have a clear support for PHP application.

Please suggest.

It must be a Java Database Server, since we are planning that we may have to distribute the applications to customers, so we need something portable and redistributable.

Comment: What are your requirements ? Does it have to be a Java Database Server and why can't you just use something like MySql?

Answer (score 1):

Most popular databases have drivers for PHP and for Java.

They also support concurrent connections. Choosing something like SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, Postgres will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)** might work fine for you. I've used it myself in projects where I both need to access it from java and PHP.